# Java keystore load works the first time, throws an error the second

Tags: java, groovy, jboss7.x, keystore, pkcs#12

I am using Jboss eap 6.2, and jdk 1.7.0_60

I am loading a keystore like so (Groovy code)

```
def keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( 'PKCS12' )
new File("/opt/test/test.private.key.p12").withInputStream {
    keyStore.load( it, 'myPassword'.toCharArray() )
}
```

This is a webapp, so I am running that code for every GET.  That works fine the first time I run it and I am able to do an HTTPS connection using that keystore.  However the second time however I get the following error on the line for the "new File(..." closure containing the keystore.load;

```
20:58:38,616 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[default]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:169) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:407) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source) [bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar:1.38.0]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:230) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.myCo.ConfirmInfo$_fetchHouseholdInfo_closure1.doCall(ConfirmInfo.groovy:114) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.withStream(IOGroovyMethods.java:1183) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.withInputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1555) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$868.invoke(Unknown Source) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.myCo.ConfirmInfo.fetchHouseholdInfo(ConfirmInfo.groovy:113) [:]
    at com.myCo.ConfirmInfo$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.fetchHouseholdInfo(ConfirmInfo$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.myCo.saml.FfmReturnServlet.doPost(FfmReturnServlet.groovy:106) [:]
    at com.myCo.saml.FfmReturnServlet$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doPost(FfmReturnServlet$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
```

I have no idea why this would be any different between the first and second time I run the code.  Any thoughts?  Suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly happening between your two invocations, however since you're not specifying a provider for the `PKCS12` a possible explanation is that between them maybe some code is adding the `BouncyCastle` provider so the second time `BouncyCastle` provider is causing the error as you can see in your log:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source) [bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar:1.38.0]
```

This could be possible because a JCE providers like `BouncyCastle` must be signed with an Oracle JCE certificate in order to be authenticated before they can be used. `BouncyCastle` provides a correct signed jar version of this code, maybe you're using an unsigned version or directly the source code.

So I think there are two possible solutions:

1. First possible solution is download the `BouncyCastle` signed jar release from: https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html, included in your classpath and also specify `BouncyCastle` as a provider in your code for the `PKCS12` creation:

```
    def keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( 'PKCS12', new BouncyCastleProvider() )
    new File("/opt/test/test.private.key.p12").withInputStream {
        keyStore.load( it, 'myPassword'.toCharArray() )
    }
```

It's also possible to use `keyStore.getInstance( 'PKCS12' , 'BC')`, however for this you have to add  before `java.security.Security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())`.

2. Use a different provider for `PKCS12`, for example `SunJSSE` which implements `PKCS12` (for more info see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html):

```
    
    // in this case SunJSSE it's loaded by default so Security.addProvider() it's
    // not necessary
    def keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( 'PKCS12', 'SunJSSE')
    new File("/opt/test/test.private.key.p12").withInputStream {
        keyStore.load( it, 'myPassword'.toCharArray() )
    }
```

I prefer the first option, however you can make a try with second one since it's more fast to test.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I tried option number 2, and it worked perfectly.  I'll play around with option 1 as well, but for the moment I'm fine with 2.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's nice to help you `:)`. However I prefer to use `BouncyCastle` as a provider because in your case to only load a pkcs12 specify a `SunJSSE` it's not a problem but take in account that in jdk cryptographic implementations are distributed in different providers and use directly, in general, it's not recommended.